# Submit can't see return false;

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I know that I must add return false; to function called in onsubmit (I added it to function and onsubmit="" in HTML). But it doesn't work... Page freshing after pressing Enter or clicking submit button.

JavaScript generated forms:

```
AnswersHTML += "<div><form onsubmit='cheking(this," + a + "," + b + ", this); return false;'><input class='put' type='text' size='40'><input type='submit' value='Проверить'></form>
```

and function

```
function checking(answer, nums, numq, what) {
var usr = answer;
if (isNaN(answer)) {
    usr = answer.value;
    if (answer.value.length == "") {
        usr = "Вы ничего не ввели!"
    }
    else {
        answer = answer.value.toLowerCase();
    }
}
if (answer == correct[nums][numq]) {
    $(what).parent().parent().append("<br><span class='right'>Ответ: " + usr + "<br>Правильно!</span>").slideDown();
    $(what).parent().parent().find(".put").remove();
    $("#board").animate({ backgroundColor: '#2ecc71'});
    $("#board").animate({ backgroundColor: '#f1c40f'}, 1000);
    if (isPhysics[nums][numq]) {
        physics++;
        $("#presult").text(physics);
    }
    else {
        life++;
        $("#lresult").text(life);
    }
}
else {
    $("#board").animate({ backgroundColor: '#e74c3c'});
    $("#board").animate({ backgroundColor: '#f1c40f'}, 1000);
    var desciptionToWrong = "<br>" + description[nums][numq];
    if (description[nums][numq] == false) {
        desciptionToWrong = ""
    }
    $(what).parent().parent().append("<br><span class='wrong'>Ответ: " + usr + "<br>Неправильно!" + desciptionToWrong + "</span>")
    $(what).parent().parent().find(".put").remove();
    $(what).remove(".pressenter");
}
return false;
```

}

Sorry for my possibly disgusting code

Here's the full page https://rawgithub.com/ruslankh/Kurchatovy/master/index.html

Problem in function because when I'm replaced function to just alert, it was fine

Comment: try `return checking(...);` instead of only `checking(...)`

Comment: there are few script errors in the `checking` method.. the param `answer` is referring to the `form` element not the `input` element... so `answer.value` will be undefined and `answer.value.length` throws an error

Comment: it won't work if your function is set onload. try putting it in the head or at the end of content in your body

Comment: @Arun P Johny but chrome console clear

Comment: check for spelling mistakes like others suggested and `this` means the 'form' not the 'input' like Arun said.

Comment: @Ruslan it is because the reload is clearing it... you can see it if you put a break point in that method

Comment: @Arun P Johny thank you so much! i get it

Comment: @Ruslan you can test it easily using firefox and firebug with the persist option set

Comment: @Arun P Johny how can i send to function <input> value when onsubmit in <form>?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably due to type. You have wrong spelling in function call that would cause an error and call goes to server.

*Change*

```
'cheking(this," + a + "," + b + ", this);
```

*To*

```
 'checking(this," + a + "," + b + ", this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inline onclick has a typo, you left one of the c's out of the function name. This error likely terminates the click handler before it gets as far as the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 AnswersHTML += "<div><form data-a='"+a+"' data-b='"+b+"' class='myform'><input class='put... "
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('submit','form.myform',function(){
        checking(this, $(this).data('a'),  $(this).data('b'), this);
        return false;
    });
});
```